# Is the function locally integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How can we show that the function $$u(x)= \begin{cases} 
   \sin(1/x) & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
   0       & \text{if } x = 0
  \end{cases}$$
is locally integrable? I know that continuous functions are locally integrable. So, it is locally integrable on $\Bbb R-\{0\}$. So, for any closed interval $[a,b]$ with $a<0<b$, should I investigate the following limits?
$$\int_a^bu(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{-}}\int_a^\epsilon u(x)dx+\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\int_\epsilon^b u(x)dx.$$ Or is there more elegant way to show it?
Thanks!

Comment: This function is Riemann integrable on any closed interval. I don't know if this same as saying it is locally integrable.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I think that this is sufficient for being locally (Lebesgue) integrable since this implies that $|u|$ is Riemann integrable on any closed interval, and hence that $|u|$ is Lebesgue integrable on any closed interval, which is equivalent to local integrability. Though there are of course locally integrable functions that are not Riemann integrable on any closed interval (indicator of rationals, e.g.).

Comment: @AlexOrtiz: thanks for clarification and details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $u$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, thus $u$ is measurable. Also, $|u|\le 1$, so $u$ is locally integrable.